# Remote desktop connection manager (RDCMan) performance issue

Tags: remote-desktop

We have setup virtual machines and my team remotely logs into the virtual machines using the RDCMan. However, as the number of remote connections increase the performance of the RDCMan is deteriorating. Also, the RDCMan is taking up more memory with increase in number of remote connection, which in turn slows down their local machine.

Can someone please help around how this issue can be resolved?

We need this setup to constantly monitor the automation script running on each machine and to instantly launch the machine that errors out for fixing the issue.

Comment: `We need this setup to constantly monitor the automation script running on each machine and to instantly launch the machine that errors out for fixing the issue` - Hmmm... that doesn't seem like the best business/ operations process.

Comment: Changing the RDP sessions to use fewer resources (lower resolution, colors, no sound, effects etc) will allow more sessions to be run on both the clients and servers. Tools -> Options -> Default group settings button. Go through the tabs and lower settings and disable what isn't necessary. As well Tools -> Options -> experience tab, set to a low connection speed to turn a lot of effects off.

Comment: And if you open the same amount of connections with the regular RDP utility (mstsc.exe), than everything is ok? I think you're asking for something impossible... Also, what Joe said - either use some normal monitoring solution or add some alerts to your script. If you need to cut the login time, than make everyone log to all servers and then disconnect so their sessions are still alive.